# timestamp gives false result

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a problem while working on my project with the timestamps. I've made a simple database to illustrate the problem:

```
id  timestamp           status
1   2014-01-14 14:14:29 old
2   2014-01-14 14:04:35 new
1   2014-01-14 14:15:19 new
```

I've ran the following query:

```
SELECT MAX( TIMESTAMP ) AS TIMESTAMP, id, 
STATUS FROM  `proba` 
GROUP BY id
```

The result is:

```
TIMESTAMP           id  STATUS

2014-01-14 14:15:19 1   old

2014-01-14 14:04:35 2   new
```

I got the right timestamp, but the wrong line of data (if i add multiple rows, i'll get the first row always).

I use phpMyAdmin - 2.11.4 if it does matter :)

What can i do about this? I need the most recent line (in the exact problem, i'll need a group by id too).

Thank you!

Comment: You are using a partial group by; expect unexpected results!

Comment: Why do you need to group by the id? I see... so you need the most recent row for EACH id.... got it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT stamp, p1.id,  p1.STATUS FROM `proba` p1 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT MAX(timestamp) AS stamp FROM `proba` GROUP BY id 
) p2 ON p1.timestamp = p2.stamp
```